# Why is `instanceof` producing different results?

Tags: javascript, prototype, instanceof

Why is the instanceof operator producing different results in the following two pieces of codes, and how is it working behind the scene?

1>

```
function MyConstructor() {}
MyConstructor.prototype = {};
var myobject = new MyConstructor();

myobject instanceof MyConstructor 
**true**
```

2>  now if i execute the following code, the result is different:

```
MyConstructor.prototype = {};
myobject instanceof MyConstructor 

**false**
```

can you explain how is the instance of operator working. i understand how the prototypical inheritance works in javascript, but i am unable to understand this scenerio.

Comment: because `{} !== {}`

Comment: @bergi sure it has. https://jsfiddle.net/7phcL3qm/. Overriding the prototype with something different leads to this behaviour...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The instanceof operator tests whether the prototype property of a constructor appears anywhere in the prototype chain of an object.

So, if you reassign the prototype, the prototype of `myobject` will not be `===` to (the new) `MyConstructor.prototype`, thus the `instanceof` resolves to `false`.

```js
function MyConstructor() {}
MyConstructor.prototype = {};
var myobject = new MyConstructor();

console.log(myobject instanceof MyConstructor);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(myobject) === MyConstructor.prototype);

MyConstructor.prototype = {};
console.log(myobject instanceof MyConstructor);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(myobject) === MyConstructor.prototype);
```

Comment: but since we are assigning an empty object as prototype in both cases, how does it know that the previous empty object is the correct prototype and not the latter ? i kind of want  to know how it is working behind the scenes

Comment: It checks `MyConstructor.prototype` at the moment that you use `instanceof MyConstructor`. With the code you just posted, the prototype is always the same (it's `===` to `foo`), so `instanceof` always resolves to `true`.

Comment: when i output `MyConstructor.prototype` in chrome dev tools, i see an empty object with __proto__ as the  Object. how does it know that it is the correct prototype

Comment: Javascript internals know that `foo` references the same object in memory as `MyConstructor.prototype`, which is the same object as `Object.getPrototypeOf(myobject)`, so the `instanceof` always resolves to `true`.